# Naive bayes classifier poor accuracy for positive negative classes

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am new to the concept of machine learning and I am trying to figure out this problem. I am using WEKA for this. I have 4 clusters who's means kind of form a square. The training dataset that I provide to Naive Bayes has 2 classes where opposite (across the center of entire plot) clusters are in same class. The accuracy for this model is not even 50 percent but when I change the classes from opposite to the same side, the accuracy becomes 100 percent. Why is this so?

[image]

Comment: you may find this forum useful http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Naive bays can not represent the solution to that problem.

There is more than one form of naive bays, but none can handle that problem. The solutions each one can solve are somewhat different.

Try to ask yourself what properties about the solution change when you "change the classes from opposite to the same side", and what it would take to represent that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Start by loading a snapshot of the data to weka to understand the data. The decide if Naive Bayes is the right algorithm for the solution

Comment: How do you know OP is using [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)? What is this wizardry you are using...